# Angular 2 throws unexpected token errors when I try to do an ajax request

Tags: ajax, angular

I'm trying to do an AJAX request with Angular2, following the official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html

I keep getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in the file `angular2-polyfills.js:1243`

I just followed the 5 minute tutorial and the Hello World example worked fine but when I tried to implement the AJAX request, the error started throwing.

What is causing this problem and how can I solve it?

My code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: 'app/main.html'
})

export class LeadsList {
    constructor(http: Http) {} // This line is causing the error.
}

// Throws the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in the file angular2-polyfills.js:1243
```

Comment: try using `private http: Http` in the constructor. instead of `http: Http'

Comment: Tried it. Had no effect.

Comment: seems there is no error in your code. will you create plnkr for your code ? ill help you out.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error in plunker. That is, the code works in plunker.. They must be requiring in some other files that I am not. Can't figure out what.

Comment: @PardeepJain Anyway, here is the plnkr url: https://plnkr.co/edit/YgMGtgHoHn99ee0PXR6F?p=info

Comment: it seems like you forgot to include http.min.js. If you did, try checking the network tab and look for the request to (http.min.js) and make sure it responds with a javascript code not HTML.

Comment: @Weblurk your plnkr is working fine in my system. try using same configuration as plunkr in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to include the http.min.js file to make it work, as well as using Inject in the constructor.

So basically I added this in my index.html file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.min.js"></script>
```

And in my component file, I changed this

```
constructor(http: Http)
```

to this:

```
constructor(@Inject(Http) http: Http)
```

Of course I had to also import `Inject` from the core library:

```
import {Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the providers attribute instead of the viewProviders one when defining your component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: 'app/main.html'
})

export class LeadsList {
    constructor(http: Http) {} // This line is causing the error.
}
```